# Dropbox Re-Installation

Tags: dropbox

I first installed dropbox with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

I couldn't figure out how to autostart dropbox, so I decided to remove it with the following and to reinstall it from the Software Centre:

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus-dropbox
rm -rf ~/.dropbox
rm -rf ~/.dropbox-dist
```

When I tried to install again in Ubuntu Software Centre, it returns me an error message:

```
**Package dependencies cannot be resolved**

This error could be caused by required additional software packages 
which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a 
conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed 
at the same time.

Detail:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

nautilus-dropbox:
```

Any help???

Answer (score 1):

Answering to my own question, I basically re-install dropbox following [Dropbox's installation guide](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx). And it seems to be working fine now.

And to autostart Dropbox (and having it running in the background), you simply type in:

```
$Home/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

and you MUST replace `$Home` with your absolute path (i.e. `/home/your_pc_name/`)